# OSX NSTextField resets attributedStringValue when text is selected

Tags: xcode, macos, customization, nstextfield, nsnotifications

I set `attributedStringValue` for NSTextField with highlighted words: [image]

but when i select text by cursor all highlighted words get usual style: [image]

I've tried following:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(controlTextDidSelected:) name:NSTextViewDidChangeSelectionNotification object:nil];

- (void)controlTextDidSelected:(NSNotification *)notification {
    self.attributedStringValue = _attrString;
}
```

But still not working while selecting.

How can i have highlighted words while text is selected?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue. 2 things help me:
 
1. set font for whole attributed string 
2. allow editing for text attributes. Please check code below:

```
[self.yourTextField setAllowsEditingTextAttributes: YES];
[attrString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:self.font range:NSMakeRange(0, [stringValue length])];
```